# Getting only "|" symbol printed all over my console, after booting CentOS 7

Tags: centos-7

I am getting | printed all over the console after I boot up. I am using CentOS 7. Can someone help, how to get over this, and why I am getting this:

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Can you include a screenshot?

Comment: "There are now 2 active connections" -- Maybe somebody else also opened the console and their L key is stuck (I think it's small L, not `|`). I suspect you can tell latest connections by examining the `Events` tab.

Comment: Or the virtual machine is set to capture some physical keyboard and somebody threw some stuff on it, so L is constantly pressed.

Comment: I tried again pressing l, it didn't get printed on the console
Is there any logs I can provide, to check further on this.